# How do I display data stored at specific index of a data-structure in C?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I am trying to replicate "Who wants to be a Millionaire ?" in the form of a C-program, in which admin adds a question(along with its 4 options + correct option) in the database through structure, which is then writing the contents to a text file. Only 1 question(along with 4 options) should be displayed to user/player at once.
Here is the structure declaration(outside main)

```
struct quest{
char ques[200],opt_a[50],opt_b[50],opt_c[50],opt_d[50],ans;
}q[25];
```

I am using gets() to take input form admin (while adding a new question and its options), like

```
gets(q[i].ques);  //'i' is the part of the loop, for allotting indices
```

The following function should display 1 question + its 4 options to the user/player.

```
void r_data()
{
FILE *fo;
fo=fopen("ques_disp.txt","r"); //this is the text file in which questions are written
if(fo!=NULL)
{
while(fread(&q[1],sizeof(struct quest),1,fo))
printf("%s\n",q[1].ques);
printf("A)%s\t\tB)%s\n",q[1].opt_a,q[1].opt_b);
printf("C)%s\t\tD)%s\n\n",q[1].opt_c,q[1].opt_d);
}
else printf("Null Pointer Error!");
fclose(fo);

}
```

Either some blank lines are printed or questions and options belonging to another question are printed together. For now let's assume that data at q[3] exists, then how do I print it out on user screen ?
Please Help

Comment: A text file? Unless it was very carefully formatted, with every line padded to the exact length, you can't expect the text file data to align when `fread` into a `struct`.

Comment: @WeatherVane the text file is properly formatted, although the text file is not a necessity, but for the time being, I'm keeping it

Comment: @AyushNanglia You should probably update your system before doing development. I don't know how your code is compiling, ``gets()`` is deprecated and ISO C11 removes the specification of gets() from the C language, and since version 2.16, glibc header files don't expose the function declaration if the _ISOC11_SOURCE feature test macro is defined. This is the warning I am getting -- ``warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.``

Comment: @AyushNanglia Pls show the exact code you are dealing with now. It is not advisable to read structs from file like this  ``fread(&q[1],sizeof(struct quest),1,fo)`` , this might be the catch

Comment: @MohithReddy I too get the same warning with ```gets()``` .

Which piece of code do you want to see ?

Comment: @MohithReddy void r_data() is the function where I expect errors to be, you may please suggest an alternative to the function because I'm not completely sure about the correctness of the aforementioned function.

Comment: If i had to guess, then this might be the line of error ``fread(&q[1],sizeof(struct quest),1,fo)``. But i cant say for sure without seeing the memory layout of ``struct quest`` and the contents of file ``ques_disp.txt``. I suggest you to adopt a different way for reading the file contents to structure. If you can post the ``ques_disp.txt`` I may tinker on it.

Comment: Here is the link to file : https://send.firefox.com/download/a1201e5b5f97a413/#0Ru7DtjkEmFoPVRnJkMmBA

Comment: The file only contains some random texts entered for testing purposes, that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the text file you are dealing with

```
1) Test question

A)a     B)a
C)a     D)a

Ans)a

------------------------------------------------
2) Another test question

A)b     B)b
C)b     D)b

Ans)b

------------------------------------------------
```

then there is no surprise for the behavior you reported.

The structures in C are almost every time padded unless you explicitly disable padding. So in all considerations (portability and lack of knowledge about memory padding prior), structures shouldn't be directly dumped or directly read from the files. Each individual field should be dumped, but that doesn't guarantee portability because of the different endianness of the systems. `8 bit` variables are an exception because endianness does not affect them.

One of the possible solutions might be to have your text file like this:

```
Test question
1    
2
3
4
2
Another test question
5
6
7
8 
3
```

The following code is able to interpret the data from the above text file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct quest{
    char ques[200],opt_a[50],opt_b[50],opt_c[50],opt_d[50],ans[50];
}q[25];

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    int ques_count = 0;

    for ( ; ; ) {
        if (fgets(q[ques_count].ques, sizeof(q[ques_count].ques), fp) == NULL)
            break;

        if (fgets(q[ques_count].opt_a, sizeof(q[ques_count].opt_a), fp) == NULL)
            break;

        if (fgets(q[ques_count].opt_b, sizeof(q[ques_count].opt_b), fp) == NULL)
            break;

        if (fgets(q[ques_count].opt_c, sizeof(q[ques_count].opt_c), fp) == NULL)
            break;

        if (fgets(q[ques_count].opt_d, sizeof(q[ques_count].opt_d), fp) == NULL)
            break;

        if (fgets(q[ques_count].ans, sizeof(q[ques_count].ans), fp) == NULL)
            break;

        ques_count++;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < ques_count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n",q[i].ques);
        printf("A)%sB)%s\n",q[i].opt_a,q[i].opt_b);
        printf("C)%sD)%s\n\n",q[i].opt_c,q[i].opt_d);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Test question

A)1    
B)2

C)3
D)4


Another test question

A)5
B)6

C)7
D)8
```

Comment: There are actually two text files associated. first one, to which the code is being written, and the second one which I just sent you.
The first one has a bad format and indentation.
It would be really appreciated if you could suggest a method without the use of text file.

Comment: @AyushNanglia I couldn't understand what you meant by "code is being written". If you are willing the read the input from the ``stdin`` you can use ``scanf`` or ``fscanf`` functions.

Comment: "Code is bring written" means when a new question is added to the structure, it is also being written to the text file (by using fprintf() and all)

Comment: See, the aim is to display information stored at any specific index of data-structure, now it doesn't matter whether you use file handling for that or do without that.

Comment: Okay, so after a few modifications, your solution worked pretty well, thank you so much for helping me out.